# Update rows with a fixed offset

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

| Id | CustomerId | Version | Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 | 1 | Some data |
| 2 | 1234 | 2 | Some more data |
| 3 | 1234 | 3 | Even more data |
| 4 | 4567 | 1 | Data |
| 5 | 4567 | 2 | More data |

Now I need to merge 1234 with 4567 while update the version to be continuous:

| Id | CustomerId | Version | Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4567 | 3 | Some data |
| 2 | 4567 | 4 | Some more data |
| 3 | 4567 | 5 | Even more data |
| 4 | 4567 | 1 | Data |
| 5 | 4567 | 2 | More data |

I've tried:
`` UPDATE Table SET CustomerId = '4567', `Version` = `Version` + 2 WHERE CustomerId = '1234'; ``

But that violates the (unique) index that exists on 'CustomerId' and 'Version'. I don't understand why. I did try a version with subqueries, but that raised other issues and seems overkill for something so relatively simple.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please add the table definition as text.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue https://dbfiddle.uk/uvEERFD6

Comment: What is the exact text of the error message about the unique index violation?  That might help to pinpoint the problem

Comment: Try adding an order by version desc clause at the end of the update statement. My guess is that if mysql starts the update with version=1, then the new version=3 value would be a duplicate.

Comment: I did not know about dbfiddle... very cool!

Comment: Adding an order by on version didn't fix it. I think my example is too small for this problem to occur.  The real table has way more data and the version needs to be bumped up with 900 sometimes.

Comment: Could you share the table definition ?